# How to use queue with concurrent future ThreadPoolExecutor in python 3?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, queue, concurrent.futures

I am using simple threading modules to do concurrent jobs. Now I would like to take advantages of concurrent futures modules. Can some put me a example of using a queue with concurrent library?

I am getting TypeError: 'Queue' object is not iterable
I dont know how to iterate queues

code snippet:

```
 def run(item):
      self.__log.info(str(item))
      return True
<queue filled here>

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 100) as executor:
        furtureIteams = { executor.submit(run, item): item for item in list(queue)}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(furtureIteams):
            f = furtureIteams[future]
            print(f)
```

Comment: Usually you would use a Queue for the consumer producer problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Comment: I am looking for some sample code to read a queue using threadpoolexecutor

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest something like this:

```
def run(queue):
      item = queue.get()
      self.__log.info(str(item))
      return True
<queue filled here>
workerThreadsToStart = 10
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 100) as executor:
        furtureIteams = { executor.submit(run, queue): index for intex in range(workerThreadsToStart)}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(furtureIteams):
            f = furtureIteams[future]
            print(f)
```

The problem you will run in is that a queue is thought to be endless and as a medium to decouple the threads that put something into the queue and threads that get items out of the queue.

When

1. you have a finite number of items or
2. you compute all items at once

and afterwards process them in parallel, a queue makes no sense.
A ThreadPoolExecutor makes a queue obsolete in these cases.

I had a look at the ThreadPoolExecutor source:

```
def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs): # line 94
    self._work_queue.put(w) # line 102
```

A Queue is used inside.

Comment: +1 a queue might be redundant here. In general, you can convert a queue into an iterable using two-argument `iter()` function: `for item in iter(queue.get, sentinel): # get items until sentinel found`

Answer (score 2):

As commented above, you can use the `iter()` function to execute a ThreadPool on a queue object. A very general code for this would look something like this:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(run, iter(queue.get, None))
```

Where the run method executes the aspired work on the items of the queue.